# Relative topology and interior points

Tags: general-topology

We know from basic topology that the intersection of a subset $Y$ of a metric space $X$ with an open subset of $X$ is an open subset of $Y$. For example, if $X$ is the real line with Euclidean topology and $Y=[0,1]$ is the unit segment then the subset $(1/2, 1]$ is an open subset of $Y$. But, from another definition we also know that in an open subset of a metric space, every point must be an interior point, that is there exists an open neighborhood of that point that is contained in the space. My question is: how can $1$ be an interior point of $[0,1]$?

Comment: I think you are having trouble distingishing when you are using the topology of the whole space and when you are using the topology of the subspace , in the topology of the subspace $1$ is an interior point because $[0,1]$ is the whole space, its open, and every open set of the subspace topology with $1$ is going to have an element of the form $(a,1]$ wich is open in that topology.Interior point depends on the topology you are using.

Comment: $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ is open in $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've nearly answered your own question.  Note that in $Y$ (that's the part you're missing), the half-open interval $( \frac 12, 1]$ is an open neighborhood.  Since $1 \in ( \frac 12, 1]$, that fact alone is enough to establish that $1$ is an interior point of the interval *in that subspace*.  Of course, $1$ is *not* an interior point of the interval in $X$.

In other words, whether a point is an interior point is a relative concept -- you need the context of the space you're working in.